# Select - Option con dos tipos de fuente

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Como puedo dar formato con dos tipos de letra o colores al atributo  de un elemento  para distnguir entre dos campos?

por ejemplo Ensenada, Baja California Mex Ensenada, sea de un tipo o color de letra y Baja California Mex se de otro tipo o color de letra y que luzca algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes colocar el código que has intentado ?

Comment: Pues codigo para eso exactamente no, solo codigo en el controlador para cargar el select de  la vista con localidad y municipio (uso ASP.NET Core MVC) pero no para dar estilo al texto en OPTION

Comment: En este caso necesitar utilizar librerías para lograr tu objetivo, cuando uses una librería y tengas algún código ya hecho puedes volver a preguntar (en caso de que algo no te funcione), recuerda leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacerlo con un `<select><option></option></select>`, no se puede. Infelizmente los navegadores dan muy pocas opciones para estilizar los *inputs*.

Comment: Debe de haber alguna manera separando y manipulando la cadena con javascript pero se muy poco o casi nada de javascript y me imagino que debe ser complicado, Conoces  alguna alternativa para ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Si se puede pero creando un control personalizado con js, css, con el control select no creo que se pueda

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como esto lo que necesitas buscar https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/ revisa la sección: Menu header

Comment: Hola Sergio, tu respuesta mas que respuesta parece un comentario y debería estar en la sección de comentarios de la pregunta, te invito a que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) saludos!